# Move "More info tab" and it's content to "details"

Tags: magento2

For **SEO reason** I would like to **move the product attributes** from "More info" Tab to details.

I could move them above and under the price info, but I want to move them below description (main content)

```
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="mage/gallery/gallery.css" media="all"/>
</head>
<body>
    <move element="page.main.title"             destination="product.info.price" before="product.price.final"/>
    <move element="product.info.review"         destination="product.info.price" after="page.main.title"/>
    <move element="product.info.overview"       destination="product.info.price" after="product.info.review"/>
    <move element="product.info.mailto"         destination="product.info.addto" after="view.addto.compare"/>
    <move element="product.attributes"         destination="product.info.details" after="product.info.description"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update file `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` of your theme and add following code inside `<body>` node:

```
<move element="product.attributes" destination="content" after="-" />
```

It will move attributes visible in `More Information` tab to product details section and will be shown below product details.

Answer (score 1):

In your theme u have to override Magento Default files.

**magento\app\design\frontend\Custom\YourTheme\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 SW-THEMES. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Magento_Catalog::js/jquery.zoom.min.js"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.attributes" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

**magento\app\design\frontend\Custom\YourTheme\Magento_Catalog‌​\templates\product\v‌​iew\attribute.phtml** as per your requirement.

```
<?php
    /**
    * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
    * See COPYING.txt for license details.
    */
?>
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
    $_product = $block->getProduct();
    $_call = $block->getAtCall();
    $_code = $block->getAtCode();
    $_className = $block->getCssClass();
    $_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
    $_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
    $_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();

    if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
        $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontendLabel();
    }
    if ($_attributeType && $_attributeType == 'text') {
        $_attributeValue = ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code)) ? $_product->getAttributeText($_code) : '';
    } else {
        $_attributeValue = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code);
    }

    $colorValue = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

?>
<?php if ($colorValue): ?>
    <div><?php echo $colorValue; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($_attributeValue): ?>
<div class="product attribute <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_className?>">
    <?php if ($_attributeLabel != 'none'): ?><strong class="type"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeLabel?></strong><?php endif; ?>
    <div class="value" <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeValue; ?></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code in Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml and add element name in after="" where you want to move..

```
<move element="product.attributes" destination="content" after="-" />
```

clear cache and check.